# How to use LaTex on a mac

Tags: installing, texmaker, mac

I'm in a class where I need to use LaTex, but there is no information on how to actually get to the place where you can use it on a computer. At the beginning of the semester the professor added it to my computer, but that computer died and I can't figure out how to get it on my new mac OS 10.13.4. The professor is not answering my emails, and I can't find any information online about getting Latex on a mac. The professor recommends using TexMaker, but I would use any setup that functions at this point. I'm desperate and running out of time in the semester so I will be very appreciative.

Comment: You need a *distribution*:  either [MacTeX](http://www.tug.org/mactex/index.html), based on TeX Live, or [MiKTeX](https://miktex.org/). You also need an *editor*: `TeXshop` is quite common on Mac, but you also can install  Emacs, TeXmaker, TeXstudio or TeXworks (included in MiKTeX).

Comment: I’m a happy user of [MacTeX](http://www.tug.org/mactex/index.html) since 2008, and I recommend it.  Just go to the page @Bernard and I have linked to, and follow the link “MacTeX Download”: both the TeXSHop and the TeXworks editors are included in the full download.

Comment: I can also recommend [MacTex ](http://tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html), which is free and includes TeXShop.

Comment: I'm very curious how you couldn't "find any information online about getting LaTeX on a Mac". If you google "latex mac" the first two links are [Get LaTeX - Mac OS, Windows, Linux](https://www.latex-project.org/get/) and [MacTeX - TeX Users Group](http://www.tug.org/mactex/).  Even if those weren't the first two links for you, they surely must have appeared on the first page of results.

Comment: Thanks Bernard, GuM and John, I'll try to get MikTex and get it working. Alan Munn, I saw those and didn't get it b/c i thought just TeXmaker would do it, thats why I posted here.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: @user4200000: Don't use MikTeX on a Mac; use MacTeX.